# When I run this program, after entering a name, I get a segmentation fault. How can I fix this to make it work properly?

Tags: c

Restauraunt.c

This program allows you to create a restaurant menu, stores it in a file, and then rates each item on the menu. It uses file functions to output everything into a file that can then be viewed through almost any program. When the program gets to the line in nametofile() 'fprintf(restauraunt, "%s Restauraunt\n\n",name);' the program gives a segmentation fault. I do not know why it is doing this, I have attempted several different methods of debugging, but none have worked. If you have any suggestions, please comment them below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

FILE *restauraunt;
char name[20];
char item[20];
char price[20];
int count=0;

void nametofile();
void rate();
void itemtofile();
void counter();
void renamefile();

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int num;
    printf("Restauraunt Creator\n\n");
    printf("Enter the name of your restauraunt:\n");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    nametofile();
    printf("\nEnter the number of items to be included in your menu:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    /* Cycles through each entry to the menu */
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        counter();
        fpurge(stdin);
        printf("\nPlease enter the name of item number %d:\n",count);
        scanf("%s", &item);
        printf("\nPlease enter the price of item number %d:\n",count);
        scanf("%s", &price);
        itemtofile();
        rate();
    }
        renamefile();
}

/*void nametofile()
{
    restauraunt = fopen("restauraunt","w");
    fprintf(restauraunt, "%s Restauraunt\n\n",name);
    fclose(restauraunt);
}*/
/* The function that sends the restaurant name to the file */
void nametofile()
{

    int i;
    i = strlen(name);
    name[i+1] = '\0';
    restauraunt = fopen("restauraunt","w");
    /* the line that gives a segmentation fault */
    fprintf(restauraunt, "%s Restauraunt\n\n",name);
    fclose(restauraunt);
}

/* rates each menu item */
void rate()
{

    int rating;
    srandom((unsigned)time(NULL));
    restauraunt = fopen("restauraunt", "a");
    rating = random() % 5 + 1;
    fprintf(restauraunt,"Your food's rating was:\t%d stars!",rating);
    switch(rating)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            fprintf(restauraunt," Here's why: Your food was not very good tasting and the price was ridiculously high.\n");
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            fprintf(restauraunt," Here's why: Your food was mildly good tasting and the price was too high.\n");
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            fprintf(restauraunt," Here's why: Your food was somewhat good tasting and the price was fair.\n");
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            fprintf(restauraunt," Here's why: Your food was quite good tasting and the price was very nice.\n");
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            fprintf(restauraunt," Here's why: Your food was very delicious and the price was amazingly low.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
/* sends each item to the file */
void itemtofile()
{

    restauraunt = fopen("restauraunt","a");
    fprintf(restauraunt, "%s: $%s\nRating:",item,price);
    fclose(restauraunt);
}
/* counts up one each time function is called */
void counter()
{
    count += 1;
}
/* renames the file at the end */
void renamefile()
{
    int x,y;
    char bridge[] = { "menu" };
    name[0] = tolower(name[0]);

    x = strcat(name,bridge);
    y = rename("restauraunt",name);
}
```

Comment: the code seems no problem. are you sure you have the write permission in the path you execute this?

Comment: Try avoiding the use of `scanf` for reading of strings or try it with field width `w` like `scanf("%ws",name);` don't use `&` for array variables, and lastly instead of `scanf` make a habit of using `fgets()` for reading strings like ` fgets(name,sizeof name,stdin);`.

Comment: @leonhart the code, in fact has plenty of problems if executed with right sets of commands.

Answer (score 3):

`name` is a `char` array. When you pass it to `scanf` or other functions, it decays to a pointer, so you do not need the `&` operator:

```
scanf("%19s", name);
```

When you read strings with `scanf`, it is a good idea to pass the size limit: this lets you avoid buffer overruns. Since `name` is declared as `char[20]`, you pass 19, because one more `char` needs to be reserved for the null terminator.